# How can I remove the path and markers from the canvas only without refreshing and changing the picture?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, path

I draw a path and marker through certain coordinates on a canvas that shows an image on the screen.At a certain coordinate point on the picture.

```
Path path = new Path();

if (!isReady()) {
    return;
} 
else if (routeList != null && nodeList != null) {
    if (!routeList.isEmpty() && !nodeList.isEmpty()) {
        // draw route
        for (int i = 0; i < routeList.size() - 1; i++) {
            PointF goal3 = new PointF(nodeList.get(routeList.get(i)).x, 
                nodeList.get(routeList.get(i)).y);
            PointF goal4 = new PointF(nodeList.get(routeList.get(i + 1)).x, 
                nodeList.get(routeList.get(i + 1)).y);

            sourceToViewCoord(goal3, vPin5);
            sourceToViewCoord(goal4, vPin6);
            path.moveTo(vPin5.x, vPin5.y);
            path.lineTo(vPin6.x, vPin6.y);

            //Draw path on canvas certain coordinate points
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
        PointF goal1 = new PointF(nodeList.get(routeList.get(0)).x,
            nodeList.get(routeList.get(0)).y);

        sourceToViewCoord(goal1, vPin3);
        float vX1 = vPin3.x - (location_img.getWidth() / 2);
        float vY1 = vPin3.y - location_img.getHeight() / 2;

        //Draw marker certain coordinate point
        canvas.drawBitmap(location_img, vX1, vY1, paint);

        PointF goal2 = new PointF(nodeList.get(
            routeList.get(routeList.size() - 1)).x, 
            nodeList.get(routeList.get(routeList.size() - 1)).y
        );

        sourceToViewCoord(goal2, vPin4);
        float vX2 = vPin4.x - (pin_red.getWidth() / 2);
        float vY2 = vPin4.y - pin_red.getHeight();

        // Draw bitmap on canvas certain coordinate points
        canvas.drawBitmap(pin_red, vX2, vY2, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw your path on another canvas (Bitmap) and only draw your path Bitmap according to your wish on the image canvas. As stated by Basile Perrenoud, the important thing is not to allocate your path Bitmap during the drawing. You could e.g. create it during the class instanciation and reuse it with a clean at every redraw.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment was useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `save` and `restore` method only store the transformation matrix and the clip area of the canvas ([See the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)). You can't remove pixels from a canvas, just draw on top of it. If you added your path on top of the image, you should make a call that just draws the image.

Note that it isn't a big deal performance-wise as long as you don't reload or recreate the bitmap.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment was useful to me.